# Where can I find the Perceptive Pixel C# SDK?

Tags: sdk, pixel, perspective, ppi

I am looking for the SDK for the Perceptive pixel touch drivers.  It looks like Microsoft took over the company, but there seems to be very little documentation on where I can find the sdk for the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

After finishing the project.  What we found out is the following, Microsoft purchased PPI.  After purchasing PPI the SDK became very locked down.  We were unable to gain a copy, however, that is not to say somebody in the future may be more fortunate.

Some of what we lost because of this was using two monitors with touch enabled, didn't allow for us to be able to touch two screens simultaneously unless we added careful placement of e.handled on touch events.